# What exactly does alarm() and sleep() do?

Tags: c++, sleep, alarm

If my timeslice is 3 seconds, I am guessing the alarm stops the execution of a process every three seconds. What does sleep do? Does it put the process to sleep for 3 seconds? This does not make sense to me - what if there are a lot of processes? Wouldn't it have to sleep for longer?

I am doing this with the round robin stimulation:

```cpp
    while (head!=NULL)
      {
              alarm(TIMESLICE);
              sleep(TIMESLICE);
      }
      cout<<"no processes left"<<endl;
```

The code works, but I just want to understand what exactly is going on as I am new to this concept.

Comment: Is this question about POSIX functions? Have you read the spec prior to posting?

Comment: This is going to be very hard to help you with, unless you give us some more context. So please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: It does seem both these functions are POSIX functions. You may find the reference here: [`sleep()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html) [`alarm()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/alarm.html)

Comment: I think (hope) you mean ”round robin simulation”.

Comment: *Why* are you guessing? Why haven't you looked it up in the documentation? And why are these questions considered controversial?

Answer (score 0):

> I am guessing the alarm stops the execution of a process every three seconds.

Sort of. It arranges for a signal to be sent to the process in three seconds. The process can then continue normally and can even ignore the signal if it wants to.

> What does sleep do? Does it put the process to sleep for 3 seconds?

Correct.

> This does not make sense to me - what if there are a lot of processes? Wouldn't it have to sleep for longer?

No. Even a process that never sleeps isn't guaranteed to get the CPU all the time. A process that isn't sleeping may or may not be scheduled to run on a core at any particular time. Once it's no longer sleeping, it's ready-to-run, and the scheduler will make the decision of when and for how to long to let it use what core.